# Sense distance with Bare Conductive's Touch Board

Tags: sensors, bare-conductive

How can I sense distance with Bare Conductive's Touch Board, like they suggest in [their product video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y3eSrUQTesg&t=27s)?

I know how I can set the touch and release thresholds, so my Touch Board is more sensitive and triggers before I touch a sensor. What I want to do is get the information how near I am. Not in centimeters or so, but a simple value telling me when I'm nearer to or farther from the sensor like in the video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a member of the Bare Conductive team, I can tell you that looking at the [grapher](https://github.com/BareConductive/mpr121-grapher) will be helpful to you. The grapher is a processing sketch that requires the Touch Board to be running the [Datastream](https://github.com/BareConductive/mpr121/tree/public/MPR121/Examples/DataStream) code. Datastream will give you the sort of raw electrode data that you're looking for.